# How to use build specific variables defined under meta data tab in bamboo in the pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, bamboo

I have defined a variable called appname in bamboo under Metadata tab in variables section (Please refer to the picture )
[image: Image of metadata variable in bamboo]

How do i get this variables' value in my pom.xml ?
I have tried the following:-

1. ran it with -Dappname=${bamboo.appname) in bamboo and refer to it in the pom as ${appname}but that wouldnt work. This is how i am referring to in my pom.xml

${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${appname}

2. ran it with -Dappname=${bamboo.appname) in bamboo and refer to it in the pom as ${bamboo.appname}but that wouldnt work(was getting null)
3. ran it with -Dappname=${bamboo.appname) in bamboo and refer to it in the pom as ${bamboo_appname}but that wouldnt work.

I am able to get the value of buildNumber that is defined in the metadata section as follows

1. ran it with -DbuildNumber=${bamboo.buildNumber) in bamboo and refer to it in the pom as ${buildNumber}and this works.  (code snippet in pom.xml)

${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${buildNumber}

How do I configure bamboo and my poms to work together so that I can access the variables defined in bamboo to flow through to the poms.
Many thanx

Comment: Why do need to reference those variables in your pom file? What is the purpose? The build number ? Have you checked the resulting jar/pom files in your repository?

Comment: My CM team wants to pass in some value to the built in jar to uniquely identify it . The plan is to get the variable name calculated dynamically but as a start we would like to get the variables passed in to the pom.

Comment: If you like to identify a jar use the information from the version control in your jar file... like commit hash in Git or something similar from other version control system... apart from that. a buildNumber related to a project version does not make sense from my point of view.. So version: 1.0.0 buildNumber:10 ? What does this means? Is this version 1.0.0 or not ?

Comment: the build Number will be used in addition to the version number . it will be something like jarname.1.0.0-snapshot.${buildNumber}.war

Comment: The build number makes no sense because from Maven point of view such a version is NO SNAPSHOT version. Furthermore the format is wrong. It should be `1.0.0-${BN}-SNAPSHOT` if you really use it... Which purpose does the BuildNumber have? If you like to make something trackable you should use information from your version control that's more related..